# Firestore create compound query from array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a compound query to do a range query.

```
let query;
category.queryParams.query.fieldFilters.forEach(function(fieldFilter) {
    query = collection.where(fieldFilter.field, filterOperationString(fieldFilter.filterType), fieldFilter.filterValue);
});
```

But it's not giving me the results I want.

I'm having a feeling that the query needs to be created chained like `collection.where().where()`

If that is the case, how can I transform the contents of my array using that syntax?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question as the contents of  your array were not included in the question, the reason you need a compound query wasn't shown and the code in the question is pretty generic. Can you update your question with more/better information so we can suggest a solution?

Comment: I need a compound query to make a range query. I want to select I.e movies between (field) year 1980 and 1989 (so it's the same field as per requirement)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you have an array named fieldFilters that contains multiple objects with a field attribute (e.g. 'price'), a filterType attribute (e.g. '>') and a filterValue attribute  (e.g. 50). If you are trying to do multiple range queries on different fields, then this will not work as stated in the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries. Solutions do exist for this problem, I suggest you read Frank van Puffelen response to the following question: [Firestore multiple range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658651/firestore-multiple-range-query).

Comment: I need a compound query to make a range query. I want to select I.e movies between (field) year 1980 and 1989 (so it's the same field as per requirement)

Answer (score -1):

Solved it with this code:

```
let query;
category.queryParams.query.fieldFilters.forEach(function(fieldFilter) {
    if (typeof query === "undefined") {
       query = collection.where(fieldFilter.field, filterOperationString(fieldFilter.filterType), fieldFilter.filterValue);
    } else {
       query = query.where(fieldFilter.field, filterOperationString(fieldFilter.filterType), fieldFilter.filterValue);
    }
});
```