# iOS - Firestore multiple orderBy and where clauses on indexes within a composite index

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do three things using Firestore:

- fetch documents whose "contentType" field is "basic",
- fetch documents that are created past a certain point in time. (5AM in the example.)
- order documents according to the "like" count.

The documents in the `contents` collection look like this (leaving out unnecessary details):

```js
{
  date: Timestamp;
  contentType: string;
  response: {
    like: Number;
  };
}
```

And here is the iOS code:

```
let dateKey = "date"
let likeKey = "response.like"
let startDate = Date().setLocalHour(5)
let timestamp = Timestamp(date: startDate)

Firestore.firestore()
    .collection(path: .contents)
    .whereField(.contentType, isEqualTo: "basic")
    .whereField(dateKey, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: timestamp)
    .order(by: dateKey, descending: true)
    .order(by: likeKey, descending: true)
    .limit(to: Constant.fetchLimit)
```

The `order(by: dateKey)` part is only necessary because Firebase demands it. Otherwise, an exception will be thrown, complaining that the where clause and the orderby clauses don't match.

I already created a composite index that says `contents
contentType Ascending date Descending response.like Descending`.

**Expectation & Results**

I'm expecting the documents to be ordered by the `like` count, and all documents to be "basic" type and created past 5 a.m. of today.

Instead, only the first two conditions are applied, and the third is completely ignored. Different mixes of two conditions work. It's the three conditions combined that is not working.

So my questions is, since Firebase documents don't say anything about having more than two multiple orderby & where combinations, is this a bug or something that's just not possible?

Comment: Firestore queries can only perform a range query or sort by one key. In your case that means you'll have to *either* sort/filter by `dateKey` *or* get the results ordered by `order`, but you can have both. This is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries), covered in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658651/firestore-multiple-range-query).

Comment: I’m sorry but I read the docs and there is only one range filter in the question, although there are two sorts. The docs say one range filter, not sort.

Comment: There are two where clauses but the first one is equality, not range. I already saw the question you linked, but it’s totally different.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please check my comments. This is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: You're ordering on two keys (`.order(by: dateKey, descending: true).order(by: likeKey, descending: true)`), which (afaik) is not possible for reasons Todd explains in the video I linked.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just checked the video. To my understanding, the video says "you can create composite indexes and sort on separate indexes as long as they compose the composite index". If you see 13:23, the composite index is "rating:noise" and the sorts are on first rating and then noise. Todd explicitly says it is possible. In my case, the index includes both "date" and "response.like", so it should be possible to sort first on date and then on like.

Comment: In the video, the time that sorting is impossible is when the composite index and the sorting key are unrelated. The example shown in the video is "city:cuisine" composite index and the sort is performed on "name", which is not in the composite index. (See 13:55). This is different from the situation above.

Comment: I think I found a workaround, but I still argue that this is not covered in your answers, the documents, or the video. The video actually seems to support my case and makes me think this is a bug.

Comment: Can you post your workaround as answer? That might help figuring out whether this is expected behavior, or a bug.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think it's working. Not sure if it will help diagnose, but here goes: I added a "tags" array in the document in the `contents` collection. The new query looks like this now: `.whereField("tags", arrayContains: Date.getDatabaseKey()).whereField(.contentType, isEqualTo: "basic").order(by: likeKey, descending: true)`. `Date.getDatabaseKey()` just generates a string with `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Comment: Here is the composite index that was generated for the latest query: `tags Arrays response.like Descending`. Previous queries generated a composite index where `contentType Ascending` was added, although I only used `contentType` for equality check.

Comment: Actually scratch that. `contentType Ascending response.like Descending` is required for the latest solution.

Comment: Can you add it as an answer? That will allow you to format it using Stack Overflow's formatting tools, and gives you a chance to accept it.

Comment: I'd like to but since it's closed I can't. I think it needs to be reopened first.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I hadn't done that yet. Done now.

Comment: I added the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround to the problem.

The original query required a composite index of three fields. So there is only *one range comparison* on `date`--`contentType` is used only for equality check--and two ordering on `date` and `response.like`, both of which compose the composite index.

Instead I decided to add a field in the `contents` document like so:

```js
{
  tags: string[]; // the new field.

  date: Timestamp;
  contentType: string;
  response: {
    like: Number;
  };
}
```

And the new query looks like this:

```swift
Firestore.firestore()
    .collection(path: .contents)
    .whereField(.tags, arrayContains: Date.getDatabaseKey())
    .whereField(.contentType, isEqualTo: "basic")
    .order(by: likeKey, descending: true)
    .limit(to: Constant.fetchLimit)
```

(`Date.getDatabaseKey()` just creates a `yyyy-MM-dd` string based on the current date.)

This query requires two composite indexes:

`tags Arrays response.like Descending` and `contentType Ascending response.like Descending`.

Fortunately, this works like a charm.

**Added Info**
The original query checked the collection for documents created after 5 AM of a certain day, and to me the range check seemed to be the problem.

As long as the `Date.getDatabaseKey()` method above generates a key with the same day for hours 5:00:00 to *4:59:59 of the next day*, this new query has basically the same effect.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It would be great to get a follow up on the issue, whether the original query was indeed something not supported or the failure was a bug. It would be great to have more info in the docs if it is not supported.

Comment: Does this satisfy the original question? *contentType = 'basic'* and *created after 5AM* and then *ordered by like*? I am not seeing anything that will pull the range data after 5AM. I may be overlooking it in the new structure or query.

Comment: @Jay As long as `Date.getDatabaseKey()` generates a string key accordingly it should work. For instance, up until 4:59:59 AM a key with the day before is generated, and starting from 5:00:00 AM a key with the same date is generated. This should have the same effect as checking for the timestamp past 5 AM. The rest is the same.

Comment: I should probably add it into the answer. Thank you.