# Firestore query by dates and times separately

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How do I query my documents by specific date and time range? Ie. I want to query documents by specific date range (01-01-2019 - 31-01-2019) and from those dates only the documents which are made in 10am to 12pm.

It would go something like this:

```
let ref = db.collection('events')

// Query by date range
ref = ref
  .where('created', '>=', new Date(2019, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0))
  .where('created', '<=', new Date(2019, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0))

// Query by time range in each date
ref = ref
  .where('created', '>=', *START TIME = 10pm*)
  .where('created', '<=', *END TIME = 12pm*)
```

So the question is how do I filter hours and minutes every day I queried? Hopefully you understand what I'm asking here! I'll update the question if needed.

**Update**
Database sturcture is following

*/events/{single event document}:*

```
{
  cafeId: String,
  created: Firestore timestamp // ex. February 2, 2019 at 10:16:00 AM UTC+2
  discount: Number,
  eventId: Number,
  productCount: Number,
  keywords: Array,
  products: Map,
  payment: Map,
  returned: Number,
  total: Number
}
```

And when I get this in the client created will transform to:

```
{ _seconds: Number, _nanoseconds: 0 }
```

Comment: Please add your database structure to see how your `created` property looks like.

Comment: Do you store `created`as a timestamp?

Comment: @AlexMamo I updated the question with the structure of the document.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes I do

Comment: When you say "Query by time range in each date" do you mean that you want to query between for example today 10am and today 3pm? OR you want all the documents that are between 10am and 3pm for any date.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec All documents that are between 10am and 3pm but also between the dates for example yesterday and today. So I would list all the events between the selected dates and then get only the events that happened 10am to 3pm in those dates.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use "standard" `where()` methods, you'll probably have to do the second filtering on your front end, from the results received with

```
ref = ref
  .where('created', '>=', new Date(2019, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0))
  .where('created', '<=', new Date(2019, 3, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0))
```

---

Another approach would be to store, in an extra field (e.g. `createdText`), your date/time value with a custom format, like for example `YYYYMMDDHHMM`, with a 24 hours format for the hours (i.e. HH).

This way the document will be correctly sorted and you can query with only one `where`, as follows:

```
ref = ref
  .where('createdText', '>=', '201902031000')
  .where('createdText', '<=', '201902041200')
```

It is quite common to duplicate the data in an NoSQL database, in particular to allow querying according to your business needs.

Comment: I think with your second snippet you'd still get all documents in the entire range, instead of a slice of each day. The only thing I can think of is filtering by two properties `createdTimestamp` (which contains the entire timestamp) and `createdTime` (which contains just the time, without the date).

Comment: Okay, I was thinking if there were simple way to use the current created timestamp. But I think I could also make cratedTime property as  @FrankvanPuffelen suggested!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes you are right! I was too fast when working out this approach! Thanks, for having pointed that out.

Comment: If you could edit the second approach to use createdTime format I will accept this as a correct answer!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you want to write an answer along the lines you proposed?

Comment: Thinking about the filtering on two properties, I think we will encounter the problem that we cannot have Range filters on different fields with `where()`.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I'm testing that approach now, but can't get it to work yet. If I do, I'll post an answer. But of course, feel free to try it yourself and post an answer if you have it working.

Comment: The error I'm getting is quite stubborn: "Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'datetime' and 'time'"

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Isn't it the problem emphasized here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#compound_queries. Red thumb down: "Invalid:  Range filters on different fields"

Comment: Yup it does. I just started doubting myself, given this question from a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54498407

Comment: Probably the two possible ways would be 1/ Combine queries for each day **OR** 2/ Filter based on hours in the front-end.

Comment: Front-end would not be a option since there could be thousands of documents. And that makes me think how is it possible to limit to only 50 documents with combining queries for each day?

Comment: How do you want to limit? 50 by day? Or 50 of all days?

Comment: 50 of all days would be preferred. My end goal is to use pagination on my table to load the next 50 and so on

Comment: You can limit queries https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data and you can combine the query in the correct order... but it is probably going to be a challenge to combine all of that in such a way you reach your goal....

Comment: I'm thinking of an alternative where you use an `array-contains`. It means you'd have to add an array where you have all possible time ranges you allow querying for, and then tag each document with whatever options it matches. So a meeting from 10-11 could be tagged as `['10-11', '10-12', ,'09-11', '08-11', '09-12', '10-13']`, if you want to allow search for blocks of 1, 2 or 3 hours. It's a workaround, but I think it should work.