# How to query only date (not time) in cloud firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query firestore collection on timestamp field but only on date (NOT TIME). For example I have three records in my database like these:

1. 7 July 2019 at 06:40:00 UTC+5:30
2. 9 July 2019 at 03:58:00 UTC+5:30
3. 11 July 2019 at 07:00:00 UTC+5:30

when I try to query with 07/07/2019 to 09/07/2019, result showing only 1 record, instead of 2. I think its due to time.

I checked this link ([Firestore query by dates and times separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517829/firestore-query-by-dates-and-times-separately)) but its not related with my query.

My query in code:

```
Date dateFrom = "21/07/2019";
Date dateTo = "24/07/2019";
Query MyQuery = mFirestore.collection("students")
.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("entered", dateFrom)
.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("entered", dateTo);
```

I think this is due to different time in database. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: From the question you linked: _"It is quite common to duplicate the data in an NoSQL database, in particular to allow querying according to your business needs."_ So why not add a field with only the date and filter on that?

Comment: Thanks for comment. But I solved this problem by simply adding 1 to "toDate" as per @Ban Markovic's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you pass date in query, it automatically append 00:00:00 time. So if you want to query with 07/07/2019 to 09/07/2019, I will advise you to try to add 1 day more to your last date. So in this particular example you should set 07/07/2019 to 10/07/2019. Or maybe another solution is to append on second date 23:59:59 timestamp.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for help :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)