# Firestore Compound Query with order and limit

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query one collection in my firestore databse

I want to query to get all the posts of a current users feed. 
I currently do so like this

```
let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("feedItems")
            .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
            .whereField("wasViewed", isEqualTo: false)
            .whereField("isResharedPost", isEqualTo: false)
            .whereField("story", isEqualTo: false)
            .whereField("createdAt", isGreaterThan: dateFilter as Any)
            .order(by: "createdAt", descending: false)
            .limit(to: 25)
        ref.getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
```

I am now adding the option for stories and want to query the same collection for feedItems where story field is equal to true

however in that case I would also need to make sure that the were only getting objects that are less than 24 hours old. So i would want my query to have two slighlty different filter sets

one with

```
        .whereField("story", isEqualTo: true)
        .whereField("postCreatedAt", isGreaterThan: storyFilter as Any)
```

and one with

```
        .whereField("story", isEqualTo: false)
        .whereField("createdAt", isGreaterThan: dateFilter as Any)
```

all other fields remaining the same and the order and limit remaining the same.

Would this be possible to combine into a single compound query?

I have tried it like this

```
let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("feedItems")
        ref
            .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
            .whereField("wasViewed", isEqualTo: false)
            .whereField("isResharedPost", isEqualTo: false)
            .whereField("story", isEqualTo: false)
            .whereField("createdAt", isGreaterThan: dateFilter as Any)
        ref 
            .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
            .whereField("wasViewed", isEqualTo: false)
            .whereField("isResharedPost", isEqualTo: false)
            .whereField("story", isEqualTo: true)
            .whereField("postCreatedAt", isGreaterThan: storyFilter as Any)
        ref.getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
```

before even trying to figure out how to handle where and how to involve order and limit and I am getting error invalid or insufficient permissions

If it is not possible to merge I will just separate them into two separate queries which will get called sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

A single query in Cloud Firestore can only perform a range filter (`>=`, `<=`, etc) on a single field. Since you seems to want to filter on both `createdAt` and `postCreatedAt`, that won't be possible.

Also see:

- My answer to [Firestore multiple range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658651/firestore-multiple-range-query)
- The [Firebase documentation on queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data), which contains this statement:

  > You can only perform range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on a single 
  >   field
- This [video explaining Firestore queries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI)

Comment: Say I got rid of ".whereField("createdAt", isGreaterThan: dateFilter as Any)" and only filtered on postCreatedAt

Comment: That should work as you'd only be using one range filter. Are you having a problem with just that range filter?