# Is Cloud Firestore a bad database selection for apps that rely on multi range filtering capabilities?

Tags: swift, firebase, mobile, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to use Cloud Firestore for a concert based app. I want users to be able to search for concerts by:

1. city or set of cities (i.e. Seattle, [Seattle, Austin, San Diego], etc.)
2. neighborhood or set of neighborhoods (i.e. Capital Hill, [Capital Hill, Ballard, South Lamar])
3. capacity or range of capacities (i.e. 0 - 10 people, 0 - 500 people, etc.)
4. genres or set of genres (i.e. Pop, [Pop, Electronic, Jazz])
5. price or range of prices (i.e. 0 - 10 dollars, 0 - 100 dollars, etc.)
6. specific date or date range (i.e. 10/2/2020 or between 10/2/2020 - 10/5/2020)

Is Firestore a bad idea for an app like this due to the following rule:

**Queries with range filters on different fields are not supported**

I saw the below post that recommends "Perform filtering on one field in the query, and on the other field in your client-side code." However, this seems inefficient in my case when you have all these variety of range filters that could be applied by a user. The other option was to combine the values into one field and again, that doesn't seem to work in my use case.

[Firestore multiple range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658651/firestore-multiple-range-query)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Also, is there a best alternative cloud based solution that I should look into?

Comment: As a follow up, I was using Realm Cloud+Query Based Sync, but due to the acquisition by MongoDB and the uncertainty of its future, I'm trying to make the switch to a different cloud based solution.

Here is an example query that would need to be performed:

`"""
city IN %@
AND (showDate >= %@ && showDate <= %@)
AND ticketPrice <= %d
AND maxTickets <= %d
AND isCancelled == %@
AND draft == %@
AND isPublic == %@
"""
`

Comment: Asking if it's a *bad idea* is really asking for our opinion and opinion type questions are not well suited for SO. Firestore can easily perform queries on all of items in your question - are you stating your want to query for all of those items simultaneously?

Comment: @Jay is there a better place that I post a question like this? Definitely open to suggestions. To answer your question, yes they would need to be able to be queried simultaneously. Users should be able to drill down to as specific as they want such as I want:

City = Seattle
Capacity <= 50 
Price <= $20
showDate >= 10/2/2020 and <= 10/5/2020
etc...

My understanding is that Firestore can't handle this. Is that correct?

Comment: SO is really for coding specific questions and for the most part, we assist with existing code that you're having difficulty with. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Firebase googlegroups are a bit more free-form. Your comment says two things; *query simultaneously* and then *drill down* which are different. If a user selects several items to query for at the same time, e.g. all users that are male *and* like pizza, that's and AND type query. *Drilling down* would be more sequential first select *male* users and then select *likes pizza*.

Comment: You can do some fairly complex queries in Firebase via their query functions but there are cases where denormalizing your data can add another level. This is a very old link but the concepts still apply in many cases; see [Denormalizing is Normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html)

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for the response. I can understand the confusion in verbiage between drilling down and simultaneous. Anyways, I gave you an upvote. I'll plan to check out Firebase groups to get feedback as this doesn't appear to be the correct place to ask.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future and wants advice from Todd who works at Google.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/r37m0Y6vfdg