# How can I get firestore document filtered on multiple fields?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have firestore recipe collection and my goal is to get a first document that matches this criteria:

```
kcal<800
carbs<100
fats<50
protein>60
```

I have just read firebase documentation and it seems that I can't perform a query that has range filters on multiple fields:

```
// this is invalid
const q = query(citiesRef, where("state", ">=", "CA"), where("population", ">", 100000));
```

Now I am being left in the dark, what do I do now, what are my options to achieve my aforementioned goal?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google’s [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries), in compound queries, you can only perform range filters on one field only:

```
const q1 = citiesRef.where("state", ">=", "CA").where("state", "<=", "IN");
const q2 = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA").where("population", ">", 1000000);
```

And, range filters on different fields are not allowed:

```
citiesRef.where("state", ">=", "CA").where("population", ">", 100000); (not allowed)
```

As a work around, you can create a cloud function where you can filter all the properties needed manually.  Then, you can create a query in a range and then filter the documents with the other desired properties.

Comment: so what you're saying, in the cloud function I need to do 1 query on calorie results, get ALL documents, then filter those document hits with javascript and return result to the client?

Comment: Check the [answer provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658651/firestore-multiple-range-query) by Frank van Puffelen, he posted a few ways this can be done

Comment: Yes, that workaround should work.  It's a bit time consuming since you will filter the properties manually, but should do the work