# Cannot use arrayContainsAny and whereNotIn at the same time in Firestore query

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing my code in flutter. In my Firestore database I want to query the users collection and get all users if

1. their boolean field `isVerified` is true
2. their array `hobbies` field does contain at least 1 hobby from the current user's hobbies
3. their `uid` field is not in the array which contains the current user's friends, incoming friend requests, outgoing friend requests, and the current user's uid.

Here is the code that I've tried. It is found within a method but this specific peice of code is giving me the error.

Note:

```
final usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
```

```
final combined = [...MyUser.myFriends!, ...MyUser.incomingRequests!, ...MyUser.outgoingRequests!];
      if (combined.isNotEmpty) {
        return usersCollection
            .where('hobbies', arrayContainsAny: MyUser.hobbies)
            .where('isVerified', isEqualTo: true)
            .where('uid', whereNotIn: [...MyUser.myFriends!, ...MyUser.incomingRequests!, ...MyUser.outgoingRequests!, FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid]
        ).snapshots();
```

I get a really long stacktrace but this is at the top:
`E/FLTFirestoreMsgCodec( 5546): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Query. You cannot use 'not_in' filters with 'array_contains_any' filters.`
I understand that I cannot use arrayContainsAny and whereNotIn at the same time but then how am I supposed to query the data in the way I described above?

If there is any other information I can provide, let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore multiple range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658651/firestore-multiple-range-query)

Comment: Have you found a solution? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo unfortunately I haven't found a working solution yet... Kyle Lynch's answer seemed to be going in the right direction but I am working around it in my project for now, I will post a solution if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you cannot use array_contains_any and whereNotIn filters in the same query in Firestore. However, you can achieve the desired result by making multiple queries and then combining the results in your code. Here's one way to do it:

First, query for users with matching hobbies and verification status:

```
final hobbyAndVerificationQuery = usersCollection
    .where('hobbies', arrayContainsAny: MyUser.hobbies)
    .where('isVerified', isEqualTo: true);
```

Get the documents from the query and filter them to exclude the users you don't want:

```
hobbyAndVerificationQuery.get().then((querySnapshot) {
  final filteredUsers = querySnapshot.docs.where((doc) {
    final String uid = doc['uid'];
    return !combined.contains(uid) && uid != FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  }).toList();
});
```

Hope this helps

For the stream try something like this:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> filteredUsersStream() async* {
  final hobbyAndVerificationQuery = usersCollection
      .where('hobbies', arrayContainsAny: MyUser.hobbies)
      .where('isVerified', isEqualTo: true);

  await for (final snapshot in hobbyAndVerificationQuery.snapshots()) {
    final filteredUsers = snapshot.docs.where((doc) {
      final String uid = doc['uid'];
      return !combined.contains(uid) && uid != FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    }).toList();

    yield QuerySnapshot<Object?>(
      snapshot.firestore,
      snapshot.metadata,
      filteredUsers,
      snapshot.query,
    );
  }
}

filteredUsersStream().listen((querySnapshot) {
  // Do something with the filtered users
});
```

A better approach would be to restructure your data model to enable server-side filtering, which would be more efficient and performant than client-side filtering. Since Firestore doesn't support array_contains_any and whereNotIn in the same query, you can consider the following alternative:

Instead of using an array of hobbies in each user document, you can create a subcollection called "hobbies" under each user document. Each document in the "hobbies" subcollection represents a hobby for that user.

Your data structure will look like this:

```
users (collection)
  └── userId (document)
      └── hobbies (subcollection)
          ├── hobbyId1 (document)
          ├── hobbyId2 (document)
          ├── ...
```

Now, you can perform the following steps to query users based on hobbies and other criteria:

First, fetch the list of users who are verified:

```
final verifiedUsersQuery = usersCollection.where('isVerified', isEqualTo: true);
```

Next, use a function to fetch users with matching hobbies by querying each user's "hobbies" subcollection:

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> fetchUsersWithMatchingHobbies(
    QuerySnapshot<Object?> verifiedUsersSnapshot) async {
  List<DocumentSnapshot> result = [];

  for (final userDoc in verifiedUsersSnapshot.docs) {
    final String userId = userDoc['uid'];
    if (!combined.contains(userId) && userId != FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) {
      for (final hobby in MyUser.hobbies) {
        final hobbyDoc = await usersCollection
            .doc(userId)
            .collection('hobbies')
            .doc(hobby)
            .get();

        if (hobbyDoc.exists) {
          result.add(userDoc);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Finally, fetch the verified users and then fetch the users with matching hobbies:

```
verifiedUsersQuery.get().then((verifiedUsersSnapshot) async {
  final usersWithMatchingHobbies = await fetchUsersWithMatchingHobbies(verifiedUsersSnapshot);
  // Do something with the usersWithMatchingHobbies
});
```

This approach will fetch users with matching hobbies more efficiently since the filtering is done server-side. However, note that this might still involve multiple queries to Firestore depending on the number of users and hobbies.

Comment: Is it possible to return a type of Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>? while doing this?

Comment: Updated answer give that a try